# Different learning rates causes error: no gradients provided for any variable

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to first train a language model (class PTBModel) separately and then attach a classifier to bias the language model towards sentiment classification, approximatelt like they do in http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html. I am able to do this when all variables are trained with the same learning rate, but I would like to have a lower learning rate for the language model since it is already trained. I found a solution for this in another post but when i separate variables as below:

```
# Get trainable variables for the language model
with tf.variable_scope("RNN") as vs:
    lm_parameters = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables()
            if v.name.startswith(vs.name)]

with tf.variable_scope("RNN_SOFTMAX") as vs:
   lm_parameters = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables()
           if v.name.startswith(vs.name)]



# Get trainable variables for the classifier
with tf.variable_scope("output_projection") as vs:
    classifier_parameters = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables()
            if v.name.startswith(vs.name)]
```

And then calculate and try to apply gradients.

```
gradients = tf.gradients(self.losses, lm_parameters + classifier_parameters)
clipped_gradients, norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, self.max_gradient_norm)

with tf.name_scope("grad_norms") as scope:
     grad_summ = tf.scalar_summary("grad_norms", norm)

print(gradients)
print(clipped_gradients)

grads1 = clipped_gradients[:len(lm_parameters)]
grads2 = clipped_gradients[len(lm_parameters):]

train_op1 = opt_lm.apply_gradients(zip(grads1, lm_parameters))
train_op2 = opt_classifier.apply_gradients(zip(grads2, classifier_parameters))

self.update = train_op2
```

I get the following error

```
[None, None, <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor object at 0x7fb6cded3f50>, <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor object at 0x7fb6cded3790>]
[None, None, <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor object at 0x7fb6cde92190>, <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor object at 0x7fb6cde92490>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 214, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "train.py", line 210, in main
    train_sentiment()
  File "train.py", line 125, in train_sentiment
    , is_training=True, config=config)
  File "/home/seberik/workspace/lm-generator/models/sentiment.py", line 159, in __init__
    train_op1 = opt_lm.apply_gradients(zip(grads1, lm_parameters))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 277, in apply_gradients
    (grads_and_vars,))
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ((None, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7fb6e0b14250>), (None, <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7fb6e0b143d0>))
```

I dont know why this happens since the following code works

```
gradients               = tf.gradients(self.losses, params)
clipped_gradients, norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, self.max_gradient_norm)
with tf.name_scope("grad_norms") as scope:
    grad_summ = tf.scalar_summary("grad_norms", norm)
self.update = opt.apply_gradients(zip(clipped_gradients, params), global_step=self.global_step)
loss_summ = tf.scalar_summary("{0}_loss".format(self.str_summary_type), self.mean_loss)
acc_summ = tf.scalar_summary("{0}_accuracy".format(self.str_summary_type), self.accuracy)
self.merged = tf.merge_summary([loss_summ, acc_summ])
```

The entire code is in the following repository, would greatly appreciate some input regarding this. https://bitbucket.org/briq/lm-generator/src

Comment: are there `None` values in `grads1` or `grads2`?

Comment: Yes, grads1 is [None, None], so the gradient is None for the variables in lm_parameters. Not sure why though. grads2 are not None, so I can run optimization for only the classifier_param variables but not for the lm_param variables.

Comment: So your first two `gradients` values are `None`. This means that first two entries of `self.losses` do not depend on the parameters you are differentiating against. `None` in gradients is mathematically equivalent to `0`

Comment: Ah, I see, not sure why self.losses does not depend on the variables in lm_parameters though since it should contain all variables outside of the "output_projection" scope.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. I had based my implementation on someone elses code and it had a `tf.gradient_stop`.